# Fedora 14 update problem

Tags: fedora, updates, yum

I'm having this problem with Fedora 14 update for last couple of weeks..
when I run yum update I get the following result:

```
> Running rpm_check_debug ERROR with
> rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:
> kernel-uname-r =
> 2.6.32.10-90.fc12.i686.PAE is needed by (installed)
> kmod-nvidia-2.6.32.10-90.fc12.i686.PAE-1:195.36.15-1.fc12.1.i686
> kernel-uname-r =
> 2.6.32.16-150.fc12.i686.PAE is needed by (installed)
> kmod-nvidia-2.6.32.16-150.fc12.i686.PAE-1:195.36.31-1.fc12.2.i686
> kernel-uname-r =
> 2.6.32.21-168.fc12.i686.PAE is needed by (installed)
> kmod-nvidia-2.6.32.21-168.fc12.i686.PAE-1:195.36.31-1.fc12.5.i686
> kernel-uname-r =
> 2.6.32.10-90.fc12.i686.PAE is needed by (installed)
> kmod-nvidia-2.6.32.10-90.fc12.i686.PAE-1:195.36.15-1.fc12.1.i686
> kernel-uname-r =
> 2.6.32.16-150.fc12.i686.PAE is needed by (installed)
> kmod-nvidia-2.6.32.16-150.fc12.i686.PAE-1:195.36.31-1.fc12.2.i686
> kernel-uname-r =
> 2.6.32.21-168.fc12.i686.PAE is needed by (installed)
> kmod-nvidia-2.6.32.21-168.fc12.i686.PAE-1:195.36.31-1.fc12.5.i686
> Please report this error in
> http://yum.baseurl.org/report
> ** Found 9 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output
> follows:
> VirtualBox-3.2-3.2.10_66523_fedora13-1.i686
> has missing requires of
> libpython2.6.so.1.0
> VirtualBox-3.2-3.2.10_66523_fedora13-1.i686
> has missing requires of python(abi) =
> ('0', '2.6', None)
> 1:kmod-nvidia-2.6.32.10-90.fc12.i686.PAE-195.36.15-1.fc12.1.i686
> has missing requires of kernel-uname-r
> = ('0', '2.6.32.10', '90.fc12.i686.PAE')
> 1:kmod-nvidia-2.6.32.16-150.fc12.i686.PAE-195.36.31-1.fc12.2.i686
> has missing requires of kernel-uname-r
> = ('0', '2.6.32.16', '150.fc12.i686.PAE')
> 1:kmod-nvidia-2.6.32.21-168.fc12.i686.PAE-195.36.31-1.fc12.5.i686
> has missing requires of kernel-uname-r
> = ('0', '2.6.32.21', '168.fc12.i686.PAE')
> mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.28-1fc13.i386
> has missing requires of
> libpython2.6.so.1.0
> pysvn-1.7.2-1.fc13.i686 has missing
> requires of python(abi) = ('0', '2.6',
> None)
> system-config-display-2.2-1.fc12.i686
> has missing requires of
> libpython2.6.so.1.0
> system-config-display-2.2-1.fc12.i686
> has missing requires of python(abi) =
> ('0', '2.6', None)
```

does anybody have a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

No, because most people have not upgraded their system from F12 and F13. What you need to do is remove the old `kmod-nvidia-*` packages as well as the ones that are dependent on the old version of Python, and then try again.